# Nodejs q library not working as it should

Tags: node.js, callback, q

I have this code which works fine:

```
var q = require("q");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

var genSalt = function(n) {
    var deferred = q.defer(); 
    bcrypt.genSalt(n, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);
        else deferred.resolve(salt);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

var hash = function(password, salt) {
    console.log(password, salt);
    var deferred = q.defer();
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
};

genSalt(10)
    .then(function (salt, err) {
        console.log("salt", salt);
        return q(salt);
     })
    .then(function (salt) {
        return hash("mypasswd", salt);
    })
    .then(function (hash, err) {
        console.log("hash", hash);
        return q(hash);
    });
```

But then in the docs I saw this:

```
// promise-translate-action.js
var promiseAction = function (arg1, arg2) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    action(arg1, arg2, deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
}

promiseAction(arg1, arg2).then(function (result) {
    doSomething(result);
});
```

Notice how the last parameter in the `action` function is `deferred.resolve`. So I thought I could do the same and save a few lines of code:

```
var genSalt = function(n) {
    var deferred = q.defer(); 
    bcrypt.genSalt(n, deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

But now my promise chain is broken, and so is my code. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in your case, because `deferred.resolve` always resolves `deferred.promise`.
But you may use [deferred.makeNodeResolver()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#deferredmakenoderesolver) instead:

```
var genSalt = function(n) {
    var deferred = q.defer(); 
    bcrypt.genSalt(n, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

or you may use [Q.nfbind(nodeFunc, ...args)](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfbindnodefunc-args), which is even better:

```
var genSalt = Q.nfbind(bcrypt.genSalt);
```